# ServerApplicationContext Class for LightSwitch 2011

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

The *ServerApplicationContext* class was added to LightSwitch 2012 in *HTML Client Preview 2*. I've tried to implement a server context for Lightswitch 2011 so I can use LightSwitch's *DataWorkspace* in  Generic HTTP handlers (ashx).

My code is now finished, and I've provide a sample below for anyone who might need it.

To use a *DataWorkspace*, a server application object must first be initialized. To initialize an application object, a *Domain Service* needs to be created. It doesn't matter what type of domain service, only that the class must exist. Any LightSwitch code must be called on LightSwitch's *logic dispatcher* thread.

**ServerApplicationContext class**:

```
public class ServerApplicationContext : IDisposable
{
   public static ServerApplicationContext CreateContext(Type domainServiceType)
   {
      return new ServerApplicationContext(domainServiceType);
   }

   private IDispatcher logicDispatcher;

   private DomainService domainService;

   private ServerApplicationContext(Type domainServiceType)
   {
      DomainServiceContext context = new DomainServiceContext(HttpContext.Current, DomainOperationType.Query);

      domainService = DomainService.Factory.CreateDomainService(domainServiceType, context);

      logicDispatcher = Application.Current.Details.Dispatcher;
   }        

   public void InvokeOnLogicDispatcher(Action action)
   {
      logicDispatcher.EnsureInvoke(action, true);
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      Action disposeAction = () => domainService.Dispose();
      InvokeOnLogicDispatcher(disposeAction);
   }
}
```

**How to Use the ServerApplicationContext Class:**

```
using (var serverContext = ServerApplicationContext.CreateContext(typeof(SomeDataDomainService)))
{
   serverContext.InvokeOnLogicDispatcher(() =>
   {
      foreach(var entity in DataWorkspace.DataSourceName)    //such as ApplicationData
      {
         //do something with some LightSwitch entities
      }
   });
}
```